# Why can't admins see data on HTML Email Status report?

Tags: email, reporting, sharing, leads

Using the standard "Send List Email" option under Leads, users are sending emails to multiple leads at once. Management wants to see the emails, and whether or not the email(s) were opened. There is an "HTML Email Status" report type that shows this information but *only if you are person who sent the email*.

Even as an admin, a report cannot be created that shows all emails and their status. When trying to do this, the report just shows blank. We checked all filters to make sure no emails were being excluded.

Checking sharing rules, the base Lead object has Public Read access.

Is there a way to create a report that shows all emails and status for list emails sent to Leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed. I can't answer as to why this limitation exists, though. That said, you could enable login access to each managers for their employees. Admins can log in as any user. While inefficient, it might be sufficient for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. If needed, I'll post as another question, but do you know of a work-around for this limitation? Perhaps a process that copies the data into object just for reporting this? `EmailStatus` object does not support queries, so not looking promising.